# WebDav with Apache 2.2 - Simply won't work

Tags: apache-2.2, webdav

I configured a WebDav directory but it won't work.
This is my configuration:

```
# Load WebDav Modules
LoadModule dav_module modules/mod_dav.so
LoadModule dav_fs_module modules/mod_dav_fs.so

# DavLock File
DavLockDB /tmp/DavLock

# http://www.webdav.org/mod_dav/install.html
DAVMinTimeout 600

# Some WebDav Fixes
BrowserMatch "Microsoft Data Access Internet Publishing Provider" redirect-carefully
BrowserMatch "MS FrontPage" redirect-carefully
BrowserMatch "^WebDrive" redirect-carefully
BrowserMatch "^WebDAVFS/1.[0123]" redirect-carefully
BrowserMatch "^gnome-vfs/1.0" redirect-carefully
BrowserMatch "^XML Spy" redirect-carefully
BrowserMatch "^Dreamweaver-WebDAV-SCM1" redirect-carefully
BrowserMatch "Microsoft-WebDAV-MiniRedir/6.1.7600" redirect-carefully
BrowserMatch "MSIE" AuthDigestEnableQueryStringHack=On

<Directory /var/www/testdav>
Dav On
</Directory>
```

The modules get loaded:

```
WebServer> ./httpd -M
Loaded Modules:
...
 dav_module (shared)
 dav_fs_module (shared)
...
Syntax OK
```

DavLock is writeable:

```
WebServer> ll /tmp/DavLock
-rwxrwxrwx 1 nobody users 0 Feb 13 20:14 /tmp/DavLock
```

This is my Testserver Token:

```
Apache/2.2.22 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.22 OpenSSL/1.0.1c-fips PHP/5.3.15 DAV/2
```

I can't find any helpfull infromations in the errorlogs.
Maybe someone can point me in the right direction.

Thanks
scratch

**EDIT #1**

Test with Windows failed with this messages:

```
192.168.1.100 - - [13/Feb/2013:21:19:18 +0100] "OPTIONS /testdav/ HTTP/1.1" 200 - "-" "Microsoft-WebDAV-MiniRedir/6.1.7601"
192.168.1.100 - - [13/Feb/2013:21:19:18 +0100] "PROPFIND /testdav HTTP/1.1" 301 364 "-" "Microsoft-WebDAV-MiniRedir/6.1.7601"
192.168.1.100 - - [13/Feb/2013:21:19:18 +0100] "PROPFIND /testdav/ HTTP/1.1" 405 362 "-" "Microsoft-WebDAV-MiniRedir/6.1.7601"
```

Test with DAV Explorer failed with this messages:

```
192.168.1.100 - - [13/Feb/2013:21:20:47 +0100] "OPTIONS /testdav/ HTTP/1.1" 200 - "-" "UCI DAV Explorer/0.91 RPT-HTTPClient/0.3-3E"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the error ... there was something wrong with the dav module. Replaced it with a module from another server that was installed the same way (and same versions).

Answer (score 1):

Try see a difference between your config file and your log file.
In the config file: "Microsoft-WebDAV-MiniRedir/6.1.7600"
In the log file:    "Microsoft-WebDAV-MiniRedir/6.1.7601"

I think you have to patch your config file like this:
BrowserMatch "^Microsoft-WebDAV-MiniRedir" redirect-carefully